# PHP - Can't update information from table

Tags: php

I can't change the information from my database.

I'm trying to update information from my database. But it's not working.

The user just need to put one existing ID from the table, and it will update the information from the specific column, in this case, it's a column called "titulo".

Here my page code:

```
    <?php
if(isset ($_POST['submit']))
{

include("../classes/administrador/Administrador.class.php");
$Administrador = new Administrador();
if ($Administrador->atualizarCD($_REQUEST['id'],$_REQUEST['titulo']))
        {
    echo "It works !!!<br>";

        } else {

        echo "its not working<br>";

        }

$Administrador->endAdministrador();
}

else{
?>
        <b>Alterar CD</b><br><br>

<form name="form3" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
  <b>ID</b>: 
  <input type="text" name="id" size="3">
  <br>
 <br>
  <b>Titulo</b>: 
 <input type="text" name="titulo">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<p>&nbsp;</p>

<?php
}
?>
```

And my function code:

```
function atualizarCD($id, $titulo) {

    $sql=  "UPDATE `cds` SET `titulo` =  '$titulo' WHERE `ID` = '$id";

            if($this->bd->executarSQL($sql)) return true;
            else return false;
        }
```

Comment: Does `atualizarCD` return true or false? Does it update nothing? Everything?

Comment: If everyone could use English for their variable and function names, that'd be great.

Comment: I see a syntax error in this query WHERE `ID` = '$id"; , who cares about the language used for variables

Comment: but if you know php, you dont need to understand the meaning of the variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed to add `'` end of the query

```
$sql=  "UPDATE `cds` SET `titulo` =  '$titulo' WHERE `ID` = '$id' ";
```

Comment: I would go a little further and protect that query, and maybe treat the ID as int if it (likely) is